# Robolectric Test an activity launched from a widget

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I've a simple widget which consists of an image and a button, the button should launch an activity. I'm trying to write a Robolectric test to test that the activity is launched when the button is clicked

I've two problems, firstly I'm getting an NPE when attempting to click the button:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: can't get a shadow for null
   at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.shadowOf(ShadowWrangler.java:415)
   at org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf_(Robolectric.java:1020)
   at org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf(Robolectric.java:671)
   at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowIntent.fillIn(ShadowIntent.java:454)
   at android.content.Intent.fillIn(Intent.java)
   at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPendingIntent.send(ShadowPendingIntent.java:48)
   at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java)
   at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowRemoteViews$2$1.onClick(ShadowRemoteViews.java:61)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
```

Also I'm not sure how to get a reference to the activity launched via the button click.

Code for test:

```
@Test
public void buttonShouldLaunchActivity() throws Exception {
    int widgetId = shadowAppWidgetManager.createWidget(HelloWidgetProvider.class, R.layout.hellowidget_layout);
    View helloWidgetView = shadowAppWidgetManager.getViewFor(widgetId);
    Button quickButton = (Button) helloWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.quick_add_button);
    quickButton.performClick();

    // Not sure how to get a handle of the activity started from a widget, this is what I have for an activity launched from another activity.
    Intent intent = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity).peekNextStartedActivity();
    assertEquals(QuickAddActivity.class.getCanonicalName(), intent.getComponent().getClassName());
}
```

Any thoughts would be apreciated, the actual widget is working (the activity is launched) but I'd just like to have a test for it.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'll update this if I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peekNextStartedActivity()` is actually a method on the ShadowApplication. The method on ShadowContextWrapper (which is what the ShadowActivity implicitly uses) is actually just a wrapper that calls the one on the shadow application.

So you should be able to do something like this, to get what you need:

```
Robolectric.getShadowApplication().peekNextStartedActivity()
```